# NewtonSoft Json.Net conditional serialization of object

Tags: serialization, json.net

I have a question concerning NewtonSoft Json.Net Serialization.
I have searched around but have not been able to find a solution.
There are some question in SO that resemble this one by the title, but none present this scenario.

What i need is to prevent certain objects from being serialized under certain conditions.

Example:
Given this class:

```
class A
{
    B b;
}
```

We can prevent B from being serialized by writing:

```
class A
{
    B b;
    public bool ShouldSerializeb()
    {
        return false; //validate the condition you want.
    }
}
```

But if we have multiple Bs, we end up having to write a function for each one:

```
class A
{
    B b;
    B bb;
    B bbb;
    public bool ShouldSerializeb()
    {
        return false; //validate the condition you want.
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializebb()
    {
        return false; //validate the condition you want.
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializebbb()
    {
        return false; //validate the condition you want.
    } 
}
```

There is another way: Use a Contract resolver

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public new static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance 
     = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, 
    MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(B))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize =
                instance =>
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        return false;

                    // The problem is that "instance" here is A and not B
                    // preventing the necessary validation

                    return false; //validate the condition you want.
                };
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Is there a way to have "instance be "B" in order to validate its internals?
- Is there a way to write the function to validate the object itself and not the member?
  Something like this:

```
    class B
    {
        public bool ShouldSerialize()
        {
             return false; //validate the condition you want.
        }
    }
```

Thank you
(I probably should post this on github, but we are so used to concentrate question in SO)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in the `ContractResolver`.  You have the `instance` (of `A`), and you have the property (of type `B`), so you just need to ask the `ValueProvider` on the property to give you the value from the instance.  That is the `B` that you seek.  Then you can inspect the `B` to decide whether or not to serialize the property.

So, for example, if class `B` looked like this:

```
class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
}
```

You could decide in the resolver that you only want to serialize `B` if `IsHidden` is false:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(B))
    {
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
        {
            if (instance == null) return false;

            B b = (B)property.ValueProvider.GetValue(instance);

            // validate the condition you want, for example:
            return b != null && !b.IsHidden;
        };
    }
    return property;
}
```

Here is a working demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/4MbQ0q

By the way, I'm fairly certain that the `instance` passed to `ShouldSerialize`  will never be null, because it doesn't make sense to ask whether a property of `A` should be serialized if there is no `A` in the first place.  It doesn't hurt to have the check in there, but I don't think you need it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late response. I will check this in the new year once at work. Happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write two methods for ShouldSerialize?

```
public bool ShouldSerialize(typeof(B))
{
    return false;
}
```

or write an overide within class B and call it as class B : A and then

```
Class B : A {
    public overide bool ShouldSerialize()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Class A {
    public bool ShouldSerialize(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

then call b.ShouldSerialize(); or bb.ShouldSerialize();

Worth a try, may have misunderstood the question but hey oh someone else will know in time.

Comment: I don't call the method ShouldSerialize, Json.net does in order to know if it should serialize the member. Its kind a like a callback. The problem is that if i have 10 Bs in class A, i would need to create 10 functions to validate each one of them.